# Joomla 4 Backend select menu item that "should" be active

Tags: joomla-4.x, menu, submenu

My new component will have an Import View in the backend where the users are able to import db stuff.
Because there are multiple types like teams, players, locations, referees, ... the imports are templates for each "type" (? idk how to call them). On the list view of each "type" there will be an import button that loads the import layout. so far so good but the problem is that joomla collapses the main menu when a view is opened that has no menu item > i don't want to have all those import menu items in my components menu.

So how can i define which menu item should be expanded / selected?
Best option would be when the current "default" view would be selected so, when clicking on import on the teams view the teams menu item should stay selected... Alternative just the components menu should be expanded.

git repo for context: https://github.com/marcorensch/com_footballmanager_2

What 've tried so far:
In my HtmlView I've added:

```
$menu = Factory::getApplication()->getMenu();
$items = $menu->getItems('component', 'com_footballmanager');
// $items is empty

// Alternative (from chatGPT was something like this:
$app = Factory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$itemId = $menu->getItems('component', 'com_footballmanager', true)->id;
$app->setUserState('com_menus.edit.item.id', $itemId);
```

tbh I know that this, especially the chatGPT hint, is some nonsense but the "setUserState" made some sense to me and i think this might be the solution?

Comment: The admin menu has entries expanded/collapsed based on what the URL is, rather than what the session data holds (which is what setUserState sets). If you have an Import button can you not just import the items, show in the message area the result, and show again the list view? If you need to select an import file you could do it like the way Joomla does it when you're installing an extension from a zip file.